# c# format double to n decimals exactly

Tags: c#, string

I would have a want to constantly display exactly n decimals after the komma..

So(for = 2) if I have 13.4589 it should display 13.49; if it is 1512.0000 it should display 1512.00 and NOT just 1512

I tried this:

```
double value; //does contain the value to dislplay
int numberOfDecimals; //does contain the number of decimals I want to have permanently displayed

///first try
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, numberOfDecimals));
string result1 = ((Math.Truncate(value * temp) / temp).ToString();

///second try
string temp = "0.";
for(int i = 0; i<numberOfDecimals;i++)
{
temp = temp + "#";
}
string result2 = value.ToString(temp);
```

neither of both does result in the wanted output(whenever  something with ".000" appears, the zeroes after the komma aren't being displayed).. what do I have to change?

Comment: Have you tried `"0.00`? And when commenting behavior, please post in the question what you observed and what you wanted, and any helpful information (like the actual format string you used) that you can think of.

Comment: `#` means "*don't* display if insignificant zero". You probably meant to use `0`.

Comment: You have to use `F2` or `0.00` to display `1512.0000` as `1512.00`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Comment: Also, you can use the [String(Char, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xsa4321w.aspx) constructor instead of constantly creating new strings in the for loop.

Comment: It worked with .ToString(("F"+numberOfDecimals.ToString())), thanks

Comment: If you "add" a number to a string, you don't need the `ToString()`. So you could just use `.ToString("F" + numberOfDecimals)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`F` Format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString):

```
string result1 = ((Math.Truncate(value * temp) / temp).ToString("F2");
```